# How to do Sum of columns in typescript and call it in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get average of all columns at the footer of my table. The data is from an API. So My table looks like

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{item.num1 }}</td>
    <td>{{item.num2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.num3}}</td>
    <td>{{item.num4}}</td>
    <td>{{item.num5}}</td>
</tr>
```

and I need to sum all that columns below like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
     <td>{{item.num1 }}</td>
     <td>{{item.num2}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num3}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num4}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num5}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>SUM1</td>
     <td>SUM2</td>
     <td>SUM3</td>
     <td>SUM4</td>
     <td>SUM5</td>
</tr>
```

The Structure of my component.ts file

```
export class AgeDisplacement {
  constructor(
    public num1 : string,
    public num2: number,
    public num3: number,
    public num4: number,
    public num5: number,
  ) {
  }
}
    export class AgedisplacementmenComponent implements OnInit {
      agemen: AgeDisplacement[];
      private api = ServiceConstants.apiUrl + '/api/v1/agedisplacement/men';
    
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
                  private modalService: ModalService,
                  private service: ReportService) {
      }
    
      getSum(index: number) : number {
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < this.agemen.length; i++) {
          sum += this.agemen[i][index];
        }
        return sum;
      }
```

What I have tried so far

```
              <tr class="even gradeC" style="text-align:center" class="success">
        <td class="info" style="position: absolute;  top: auto;  width: 73.5px;">All&nbsp;teams</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> {{ getSum(0) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(1) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(2) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(3) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(4) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(5) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(6) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(7) }}</td>
        <td>{{ getSum(8) }}</td>
      </tr>
```

I keep on ending up with an error

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>     at AgedisplacementmenComponent.getSum
> ```

Comment: The code for calculating the sum should work, however, you don't initialize the `agemen` field anywhere, which is why it fails.

Comment: Hi @oktupol i have initialized it here `agemen: AgeDisplacement[];` after the export class

Comment: `agemen: AgeDisplacement[];` is a declaration, not an initilization. You must give it a value to initialize it. Meanwhile it's undefined (so it explains the error `'length' of undefined`)

Comment: That's the declaration not initialisation. It would be like this:
  agemen: AgeDisplacement[] = [];

Comment: @arriff You have declared it there - not initialised. Type agemen: AgeDisplacement[] = []; to initialise it as well.

Comment: Or within constructor this.agemen = [];

Answer (score 0):

the code you shared do not contain the part where you have to initialize "this.agemen" it should be done once you call the api and then run your getSum() method.